# Angular : Conditionally changing FormControl

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular4-forms, form-control

I am creating a formGroup Validation based on a toggle value

```
public toggle:boolean=false;


ngOnInit(): void {
          this.formGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
          formArray: this.formBuilder.array([
            this.formBuilder.group({
              toggleFormCtrl: [this.toggle, null],
              fnameFormCtrl: ['', this.checkInputs.bind(this)],
              lnameFormCtrl: ['', this.checkInputs.bind(this)],
              addressFormCtrl: ['', this.checkMiInput.bind(this)]
            }),
         ])
       });

  }

checkInputs(c: FormControl) {
if (this.toggle) {
  return c.value === '' ? null : {
    checkinputs: {
      valid: false
    }
  };
} else {
  return c.value ? null : {
    checkinputs: {
      valid: false
    }
  };
}

}



checkMiInput(c: FormControl) {
    if (this.toggle) {
      return c.value ? null : {
        checkMiInput: {
          valid: false
        }
      };
    } else {
      return c.value === '' ? null : {
        checkMiInput: {
          valid: false
        }
      };
    }
  }
```

Based on the toggle value I want to validate the form. When toggle value is `true`, the form should validate formControl `addressFormCtrl` and when the toggle is false, it should validate `fnameFormCtrl` and `lnameFormCtrl`
My code isn't working well. What am I missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I turn on/off my validation with a method like this:

```
setNotification(notifyVia: string): void {
    const phoneControl = this.customerForm.get('phone');
    if (notifyVia === 'text') {
        phoneControl.setValidators(Validators.required);
    } else {
        phoneControl.clearValidators();
    }
    phoneControl.updateValueAndValidity();
}
```

This code uses `setValidators` to set the validator for the control and `clearValidators` to clear the validators for the control.

In your case, you would need to turn it off and on for several controls.

Notice also the `updateValueAndValidity`. This is required to ensure that the validators are actually changed.

This code is called from the `ngOnInit` method with code like this:

```
    this.customerForm.get('notification').valueChanges
                     .subscribe(value => this.setNotification(value));
```

If the user changes the `notification` radio button, the code in the `subscribe` method is executed and calls `setNotification`.

Answer (score 2):

Transform toogle into a observable as Subject, now you suscribe to the new subject. In the suscription you can use the method named **setValidators** that replace you form control validators with you want.

https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#setValidators

Example, toogle.suscription(value => this.updateValidators(value));

Answer (score 0):

You need an function with:

```
this.form['controls']['view'].setValidators([Validators.required]);
this.form['controls']['view'].patchValue(yourValue);
```

I use this code if get cetain properties from the backed based on input.
I noticed when set the validator it need to patch the value to otherwise it not update for some reason.